# There is an issue for using TextInput on android in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a issue for using the TextInput on android in react native
I have use following code.

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

```
  </View>
);
```

}
}

then screen is follow:

[screenshot before tap TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeEj3.png)

When I tap TextInput view then screen is comes up like using keyboardavoidingview.

[screenshot after tap TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9O4v.png)

it's on android, but on ios there is no any effect.
I have no use any other component.

My package.json is following:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.50.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

On Android why there is an effect like as using KeyboardAvoidingView although I never use that component?
And why it is ok on ios?
I'm very happy to hear your advance. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use `TextInput` it is recommended you use a `Scrollview` as a parent view of it with a prop `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`. This will create uniformity whenever keyboard pops up.

**Edited :**

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      <View style={{paddingTop:20}}> //Inside ScrollView flex doesn't work so use padding to control spacing 

          // Add your <TextInput> Tag here !!

       </View>
     </ScrollView>
</View>
```

I Hope I could help you.

Comment: Hi, Ron. I'm very happy to hear your answer. As u can see my screenshots when tapping the TextInput then this component layout is change and I don't like this. and could u share example code for me?

Comment: I Edited. Do check

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much. I hope you will help me in future.

Comment: Hey @WaterFlower, as you are a new contributer to Stack Overflow. For answers you are completely satisfied with, It would be great if you could tick mark or upvote for those answers only. This will help to encourage the community to be more involved. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I'm new to StackOverflow. Could you tell me how can I tick mark or upvote for your answer?

Comment: Side of my answer there is a grey color tick mark and grey color triangle facing up. Just press on it.

Comment: Hi, do you mind having a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171984/react-native-webview-crashing-on-android