# React native webview crashing on Android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

i have screen inside my app where the user is required to enter their 3 digit code to continue. When the user, enters their 3 digit code, a modal with a webview inside is opened. The webview then automatically redirects the user to the correct url where parameters are attached to the url based on my backend and updates a status field inside my database.

On ios, i have used onShouldStartLoadWithRequest to listen to changes inside the url then once the desired url is achieved i Alert the user that it was successful and navigate the user back to the home screen.

On android, since onShouldStartLoadWithRequest doesnt work, i have created an API call to my backend to fetch the value of status every 2 secs and then if status is successful, Alert the user.

On ios, everything is working without any crashes.

On android, 2 crashes occur:

1. after the webview modal is closed, the textinput field crashes and i am no longer able to enter any input inside (even the placeholder is not visable)
2. after the webview modal is closed, the alert does not appear

Here is my code:

```
function Screen({navigation,route}) {
  let myWebView;

const [uploadVisible, setUploadVisible] = useState(false);
const[cvv,setCvv]=useState('');
const[authenticateWebView,setAuthenticateWebView]=useState(false);

const handlePayment=async()=>{
setUploadVisible(true);
setUploadVisible(false);
setAuthenticateWebView(true)
} 

const[statusUpdated,setStatusUpdated]=useState(false);
const intervalRef = useRef();

const everyTwoSeconds=async()=> {
  console.log('android')
  const response = await transactionsApi.getTransaction(route.params.transaction.id);

  console.log(response)

  if(response.data.status==='paid'){
    setStatusUpdated(true);
    setAuthenticateWebView(false);
    {authenticateWebView===false?
      Alert.alert('Payment successful',"Your card has been charged", 
    [
      { text: 'Yes',
        onPress:()=> {
          navigation.navigate(routes.HOME);
        }},
      { text: 'Cancel',style:"cancel" },
    ]):null}
  }
}

const myInterval =()=>{
    intervalRef.current=setInterval(()=>{
        everyTwoSeconds()
    }, 5000);
} 

useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = intervalRef.current;
  
    // also clear on component unmount
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (statusUpdated===true) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [statusUpdated]);

  const modal = React.createRef();

const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
     'keyboardDidShow',
     () => {
       setKeyboardVisible(true); // or some other action
     }
   );
   const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
     'keyboardDidHide',
     () => {
       setKeyboardVisible(false); // or some other action
     }
   );

   return () => {
     keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
     keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
   };
 }, []);

 const keyboardHeight = useKeyboard();

return(
  <>
      
{
  authenticateWebView?
  <Modal visible={authenticateWebView}>
    <View style={{  
      flex : 1,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>

          <View style={{
            flex:1,
            width:'100%',
            flexDirection:'row',
            backgroundColor:colorScheme==='dark'?colors.black:colors.white,
            justifyContent:'space-between',
            alignItems:'center',
            paddingTop:Platform.OS='ios'?40:0
            }}>
            
              <TouchableOpacity style={{
            backgroundColor:colorScheme==='dark'?colors.black:colors.white,
            justifyContent:'flex-start',
            alignItems:'center',
            paddingLeft:20
            }}
            onPress={()=>{setAuthenticateWebView(false);clearInterval(myInterval)}}
            >
                <Text style={{color:colors.primary,fontSize:15,fontWeight:'700'}}>
                  Cancel
                  </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

  <View style={{height : '90%',width:'95%',backgroundColor:colors.white}}>
<WebView
style={{flex:1}} 
source={{html:`${url}`}}
ref={el=>myWebView=el}
onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
  console.log(navState)
}}
/>
</View>
</View>
</Modal>
:null
}
  
<View style={{
  flex:1,
  backgroundColor:colorScheme==='dark'?colors.dark:colors.white,
  paddingBottom:colorScheme==='dark'?0:0,
  marginBottom:0,
  borderTopRightRadius:10,
  borderTopLeftRadius:10,
  paddingTop:0,
  marginTop:0
}}>

<View 
style={{
  backgroundColor:colorScheme==='dark'?colors.black:colors.white,
  borderRadius:5,
  borderWidth:1,
  borderColor:colors.primary,
  height:30,
  marginTop:10,
  marginHorizontal:20
  }}>
<TextInput 
          placeholder={"CVV"}
          maxLength={3} 
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          onChangeText={cvv => setCvv(cvv)}
          value={cvv.value}
          />
</View>

<AppButton title="Pay now" 
onPress={()=>{
  console.log(cvv.length)
  if(cvv.length!==3){
    return Alert.alert('Please enter your card security code (CVV).',"This can be found on the back of your card.")
  }
  handlePayment();
  Platform.OS!=='ios'?myInterval():null;
}}
/>
</View>

</>
);
}
```

Before webview submission:

[image]

after webview submission

[image]